# Is it possible to continue download file after app terminate from background

Tags: ios, objective-c, xcode, nsurlsession

I want to continue download file when user terminate application from background.
I'm using **Heikowi/HWIFileDownload** this demo.
This is demo link which I'm used : **https://github.com/Heikowi/HWIFileDownload**
In this demo work perfactly

1. Download file in background foreground.
2. Pause and resume downloading file.
3. Resume downloding after app remove from background.

But I want to continue the download file, if user killed application from background.

[image]

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If the user removes app from the background, system won't wake it up to allow app to continue downloading.

**Updated**

App is woken up only if it was terminated or suspended **by the system**. This is not the case when user does this. Apple considers that if user kills app, he doesn't want it to be running anymore.

Comment: pls check my attached screen shot

Answer (score 0):

If web server supports Partial content and you implement proper business logic, then it's more than possible

Answer (score 0):

The author of the `HWFileDownload` is already said is not possible.

https://github.com/Heikowi/HWIFileDownload#force-quit

As said by other answers you need to do it by your self, if your webserver allowed to resume download then you can continue with the downloading.

Comment: Please give me any example or demo project ?